# Check if person's id exists in a function's dictionary

Tags: python, django

I have this code to check if a person exists given their id. If they do exist, it has to print the name and last name. If they don't exists, it has to print some error. The thing is, my code only prints the error even though I tried the code with a number I know corresponds to an existing person. How do I fix that?

This is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests
from django.views.generic import FormView
from .forms import MonotributoForm
from app.ws_sr_padron import  get_persona

class ConstanciaInscripcion(FormView):

   def get(self, request):
      return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
   
   def post(self,request):

       form = MonotributoForm(request.POST)
           
       try:
           cuit_r = int(request.POST.get('cuit', '-1'))  # Get 'cuit' with default of -1
       except ValueError:
           pass   
       
       response= get_persona(cuit_r)

       if response is True:
           print(response["persona"]['name'])
           print(response['persona']['lastname'])
       else:
           print("cuit doesn't exist")

       if form.is_valid():
           cuit = form.cleaned_data.get('cuit')
           email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
           cuit.save()
           email.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('app/constancia-inscripcion.html')


       return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
```

The code for get_persona (I cannot modify this as I did not write it and it was given to me this way):

```
def get_persona(cuit_requested, ta_sign=None, ta_token=None):
   try:
       if ta_sign is None and ta_token is None:
           ta_sign, ta_token = wsaa.get_ta_sign_token('ws_sr_padron_a13')
       client = Client(padron13_wsdl)
       response = client.service.getPersona(
           sign=ta_sign,
           token=ta_token,
           cuitRepresentada=cuit_consultante,
           idPersona=cuit_requested,
       )
       return serialize_object(response, target_cls=dict)
   except Fault as e:
       if e.message == 'No person with Id':
           return None
       elif e.message == 'inactive':
           return 'inactive'
       print('Error: ', e)
       return None
   except Exception as e:
       print('Error: ', e)
       return None
```

Result of get_persona with an existing id (tried on terminal):

```
{'metadata': {'fechaHora': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 4, 15, 13, 54, 738000, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '-03:00'>), 'servidor': 'linux11b'}, 'persona': {'apellido': 'POLAR', 'estadoClave': 'ACTIVO', 'idPersona': 2231230211, 'mesCierre': 12, 'nombre': 'MAURICIO', 'tipoClave': 'CUIT'}}
```

The output of response on it's own seems to be None for some reason.

Comment: Can you post the code for `get_persona` and an example value for `request.POST['cuit']`? Judging from what you have here, the `int(request.POST.get(...))` could be raising a `ValueError`, but you just `pass` instead of handling it. Or it could be that `get_persona` is responding with a value that is not `True`.

Comment: @damon I updated it. Yes, I think it has to do with the True but I don't know how else to try to make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the conditional in your code: `if response is True`.

If you look at the value that `get_persona` returns, it can be the result of the function `serialize_object(...)`, `None`, or `"inactive"`.

If the `serialize_object(...)` function returns a `None` or the string `"inactive"`, the statement `response is True` will be false.

```py
>>> type(True)
bool
>>> type({"a": 1})
dict
>>> type("inactive")
str

# To test this, I created this function
>>> def test_response(response):
        return response is True

>>> test_response(None)
False
>>> test_response({"persona": True})
False
>>> test_response("inactive")
False

# The only value of response that `is True` is the value `True` itself!
>>> test_response(True)
True
```

What you want to do is change your conditional to check for a useful `response` value. In this case, you could test if the `response` value is a `dict`, but what if it doesn't have the `persona` value -- or what if the `persona` exists, but it doesn't have a `nombre`?

```py
>>> response = {"a": 1}
>>> response["persona"]["nombre"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'persona'

>>> response = {"persona": None}
>>> response["persona"]["nombre"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

A better solution than an `if` statement would be a `try`/`except`, which can handle both types of errors gracefully and default to the invalid/error case.

```py
response = get_persona(cuit_r)

try:
    nombre = response["persona"]["nombre"]
    apellido = response["persona"]["apellido"]
except KeyError:
    nombre, apellido = None, None
    print("get_persona response is missing keys!")
except TypeError:
    nombre, apellido = None, None
    print("get_persona response had wrong type!")
else:
    print("get_persona returned a valid response!")
    print("nombre:", nombre)
    print("apellido:", apellido)
```

#### Update #1

Based on your comments, it also sounds like you're having trouble with the `cuit_r` value as well. You should change your code to properly handle the possible exceptions as separate statements:

```py
try:
    cuit_r = int(request.POST["cuit"])
except KeyError:
    print("The key 'cuit' was missing from the POST data.")
    print("Defaulting to cuit_r = -1")
    cuit_r = -1
except TypeError:
    print(
        "The 'cuit' value is the wrong type:",
        type(request.POST["cuit"]),
    )
    print("Defaulting to cuit_r = -1")
    cuit_r = -1

print(f"Resolved value of cuit_r: {type(cuit_r).__name__}({cuit_r!r})")
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This makes a lot of sense but when I type a number I know exists, I get the print from TypeError, even though there's no error. Why is that if the person does exist and has a "nombre" and "apellido"?

Comment: That means that `get_persona` isn't returning the type of response that's expected -- either `response` is not a `dict` or `response["persona"]` is not a `dict`. Before the `try` statement, check what the value of `response` is by adding: `print(repr(response))`

That should point you in the right direction. If you're still having trouble, add the output to your question and let me know by commenting here.

Comment: Thank you. The response is just None for some reason but if I try the function with the number in the terminal, I do get the data. I also get the data I need with response["persona"]["nombre"] but only in the terminal. Maybe the problem is in the int(input)? For some reason it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I just updated my answer to try and help you debug the issue with `cuit_r`.

Comment: Thank you for the new changes! That points me to the error but I don't understand why the error is there at all. I get KeyError but I did type the right number so how can this be?

Comment: The `KeyError` means that the `request.POST` `dict` doesn't have a `"cuit"` key in it. Before the `try` statement, see what keys exist using: `print(request.POST)`. The keys in the `request.POST` dict depend on the form html that's sending it.

Comment: Thank you! The error was that "cuit" was actually "CUIT", such a silly mistake. Thank you for all the help, it solved all my issues!